# studentslearn.map() is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, javascript-objects

I tried mapping data with react from an array nested in a firestore collection but I get an error:

> array.map() is not a function.

This is how I tried tried mapping from the the collection, where courseinfo is the state storing returned data from firebase

```
{courseinfo.students_learn.map((students)=>{
                        return(<CourseLearnItem>{students}</CourseLearnItem>)
                    })}
```

This is the structure of the collection I'm trying to get data from the students_learn field

[image]

Comment: Where is `courseinfo` defined in your *state*? Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also the `students_learn` seems to be a string so you would have to parse it first.

Comment: Try to log courseinfo.students_learn to see if its a array or null or somethings else, if its not an array  possible to get this error.

Comment: Could you please confirm me how are you saving the data in the students_learn field? for what I am able to see you are using an array between "", this makes me think that you are not able to map the array because you have saved the data as a string, and the function is not able to recognize and find the data. Could you please confirm me if this is your case?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, `students_learn` is a string and map is a function for arrays.Since you are trying to apply array function to String it throws an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should parse the `courseinfo.students_learn` first because from what I saw it is a string.

```js
const studentList = JSON.parse(courseinfo.students_learn);
return (
  <div>
    {studentList.map((student) => (
        <CourseLearnItem>{student}</CourseLearnItem>
    ))}
  <div/>
);
```

Comment: i get Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.  when i run that code is there a possible way to resolve this

Comment: make sure you check that the variable isn't already an array, because otherwise it will throw an SyntaxError